# General advice on creating "standard" components across multiple languages

Tags: java, python, .net, design-patterns

Long story short: I am looking for advice on how to go about creating a "standard" library of components/wrappers that are functionally identical across multiple languages. The end goal is to have common library that all software uses so that changes to our backend can be easily made without having to touch 100+ pieces of software

A simple example would be a logging wrapper that takes a log name and verbosity level. It will have a default logging/timestamp format, directory location, and .log extension. The backend implementation will vary but the output should be the same.

Java

```
public Logger log = new Logger("mylog", 20);
log.info("This is a Java log")
```

Python

```
log = Logger("mylog", 20)
log.info("This is a Python log")
```

C#

```
public Logger log = new Logger("mylog", 20);
log.info("This is a C# log")
```

Output in mylog.log:

> 2018-12-04 15:00:00 | INFO | This is a Java log
>
> 2018-12-04 15:00:01 | INFO | This is a Python log
>
> 2018-12-04 15:00:02 | INFO | This is a C# log

Assuming the following:

- Languages used are Java, C#, Python
- GitHub is used
- Number of library components will start at 3, but grow slowly to potentially 10+.
- First three components/wrappers will be logging, SQL connection, configuration file reader/writer
- Each language would be released, such as a DLL or JAR.
- There are over a dozen developers and 100+ scripts/apps/GUIs, etc.

The questions that I have and would like advice about are:

1. Should each language have its own repository? (I can think of pros/cons of each and have started to lean having on separate repos)
2. How to handle different IDEs? e.g. Java with Eclipse or NetBeans. Should the build be run from cli?
3. Thoughts on versioning? i.e. all components are initially released at version 1.0. C# logging gets an update and is now version 1.1. Ideally, and with discipline, Java and Python should be updated at the same time and be versioned identically.
4. Any pitfalls to this approach?
5. Is this approach common in small or large organizations?
6. Am I crazy for trying this?!

Longer story: we have machines (literal machines in manufacturing) as well as PCs that range from 0-25 years old. PLCs, Windows/Linux/Mac, mobile, GUI/command line apps, etc. This is something that **cannot** be changed because it is simply impossible to update everything.

Due to this, we use multiple languages within our organization, mainly Java, Python, and .NET. Also, because of wide variety of machinery and PCs, we have 100+ scripts, applications (both simply and very complex), web interfaces, etc. They are used for things like automated data collection, manual data entry, or graph display.

Since there are so many different programs created by many developers, we are attempting to create a set of common components that are essentially the same across multiple languages.

Comment: I would advise against that. Each language has it's strength and weaknesses. If you create something like this, you restrict the API to the lowest common level, ignoring all the recommendations that each language has for it's APIs. Such an API won't feel native to each language.

Comment: If you want a common API, try to develop a REST based API, that each language can import. You will probably get much better results, for a fraction of the work.

Comment: If you want the same API in 3 languages, first create 1 specification, then implement it in 3 languages. Each language has its own repository, IDE, build tools, but they all share the same specification.

Comment: Logging is a great example of something you *should not* do this way.  The standard logging framework of each language is going to be better than anything you come up with.  Just document  a standard format for log messages, and require all coders to adhere to it.  Code reviews are essential.  I strongly recommend against trying to enforce this with an “official” home-grown logging method;  you’ll just end up with every class coupled to that one, and developers are no more likely to use it than they are to use a documented logging format.

Comment: I am not suggesting to create a new logging implementation in each language. I want to use the native logging frameworks that _are_ available to each language and wrap it so that they appear to be functionally the same. Also, it would allow for easier changes to the 100+ pieces of software that we have.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn REST is what we did start using but the unfortunate reality for old manufacturing is that the network is not dependable and we need all equipment to be able to run even when the network is temporarily down. Most all of our software will cache locally and then upload once the network is restored.

Answer (score 0):

- Should each language have its own repository? (I can think of pros/cons of each and have started to lean having on separate repos)

I would say yes, at the very least it is much easier to merge them into a single repo later than it would be to split them off. Not to mention branch management, PR/Code Review, code cleanup, source code searching... It seems unlikely that a developer will commonly have multiple languages open, why force them to do so if there are numerous downsides.

- How to handle different IDEs? e.g. Java with Eclipse or NetBeans. Should the build be run from cli?

This might depend on if your devs use a standard OS for their machines, if so i would say use the features bundled into the IDE, thats why they are there. If they use multiple OS's it might be worth considering using standard cli tools instead.

- Thoughts on versioning? i.e. all components are initially released at version 1.0. C# logging gets an update and is now version 1.1. Ideally, and with discipline, Java and Python should be updated at the same time and be versioned identically.

I would go with a x.y.z versioning setup with x and y representing major and minor revisions to the specification and z representing changes to the implementation. So, find a bug in the C# logger, and increment z but x.y remains the same. This shows at a glance which standards are being used (x.y spec) and how many patches have been released to the language's implementation (z)

Could also be done with just y.z (y = spec version, z = code revision on that spec) but if your org is anything like mine scope creek is a real thing and the specs will change constantly.

- Any pitfalls to this approach?

The old adage about keeping synchronized data in parallel arrays (one is always out of date), most certainly will apply here. If your org will not allocate the time to develop and maintain a spec, i would not even start.

I think going into this you would need to answer this: what is the goal? For the code to look/function the same? Or, for it to produce the same output? If the former, you are likely to run into numerous issues implementing this. If the latter, the i would suggest creating a high-level concrete specification for the projects.

Side note: depending on if this is applicable, it might be worth creating a unified testing project such that the exact same tests can be run against all of the projects.

- Is this approach common in small or large organizations?

Not that i have seen, but if the goal is that programmers can become familiar with a standard set of utils/tools provided by the org so as to allow programmers to program faster in multiple languages, then sure it make sense.

- Am I crazy for trying this?!

Probably, let me know how it works out for you. On paper it makes sense, however as @
Johannes Kuhn mentioned in a comment that you could end up in a situation where you handicap each languages strengths to the weakest language for a task. I think you could resolve this by keeping the spec at a high level, but i think this is the type of problems most likely to sink the project.